# Kendo Grid: How to append to URL

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I want to make my update url for my Kendo grid dynamic. I want to be able to go from "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/update" to "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/update/100"

I've followed the Kendo tutorial for custom data sources. I modified the "parameterMap" function and can change the value of the update url but it does not seem to bind.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoDemo.Models.EmployeeViewModel>()
            .Name("NCSBEGrid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.employee_name).Title("Name");
                columns.Bound(p => p.employee_age).Width(140).Title("Age");
                columns.Bound(p => p.employee_salary).Width(140).Title("Salary");
                columns.Bound(p => p.profile_image).Hidden(true);
                columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(110).Title("Delete");
            })
            .ToolBar(toolbar =>
            {
                toolbar.Create();
                toolbar.Save();
            })
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
            .Pageable()
            .Navigatable()
            .Sortable()
            .Scrollable()
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Custom()
                .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler")         
                )
                .Batch(true)
                .PageSize(20)
                .Schema(schema => schema
                .Model(m => m.Id(p => p.id)))
                .Transport(transport =>
                {
                    transport.Read(read =>
                        read.Url("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
                            .DataType("json")
                    );
                    transport.Create(create =>
                        create.Url("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/create")
                        .Type(HttpVerbs.Post)
                        .DataType("json")
                    );
                    transport.Update(update =>
                        update.Url("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/update")
                        .Type(HttpVerbs.Put)
                        .DataType("json")
                    );
                    transport.Destroy(destroy =>
                        destroy.Url("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/update")
                        .Type(HttpVerbs.Delete)
                        .DataType("jsonp")
                    );
                    transport.ParameterMap("parameterMap");
                })
            )
)
<script>
    function parameterMap(options, operation) {

        var grid = $("#NCSBEGrid").data("kendoGrid");

        if (operation == "create") {

            var params = { "name": options.models[0].employee_name, "salary": options.models[0].employee_salary, "age": options.models[0].employee_age };

            return JSON.stringify(params);
        }
        else if (operation == "update") {
            var params = { "name": options.models[0].employee_name, "salary": options.models[0].employee_salary, "age": options.models[0].employee_age };

            grid.dataSource.transport.options.update.url = "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/update/" + options.models[0].id;

            //grid.dataSource.sync;
            //grid.dataSource.transport.options.update.data = JSON.stringify(params);           
            //grid.dataSource.read; 

            return JSON.stringify(params);
        }
    }

    function error_handler(e) {
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function () {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
            });
            alert(message);
        }
    }
</script>
```

In javascript section I expect the update url to include the id at the end. Currently it is updating but when the call to the dummy api is made the id is omitted. It seems easy to do but I cannot figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could try switching your update Url from an absolute address to the name of a JS function, similar to the way your `parameterMap` function is referenced. **I'm not 100% certain this is possible using MVC** ... I couldn't find any examples or documentation to support this, but I know this technique works if you are using the native JS library. See [JS docs](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/transport.update#transportupdateurl) for an example of what I mean.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've been sick and slow for the past week. What I ended up doing was using a handler.

Comment: No problem, hope you're feeling better. Sorry I couldn't be of more help; I haven't really used the kendo MVC library much but I knew what you wanted was possible.

Answer (score -1):

I used a handler to add the employee id to the url. Thank you Joe for the help.

MVC: 
transport.Update(new { url = new Kendo.Mvc.ClientHandlerDescriptor() { HandlerName = "update" } });

Javascript:

```
function update(options) {

    let params = {
        "name": options.employee_name,
        "salary": options.employee_salary,
        "age": options.employee_age
    };

    let json = JSON.stringify(params);

    $.ajax({
        method: "PUT",
        url: "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/update/" + options.id.toString(),
        dataType: "json",
        data: json
    });

}
```